# Is there a way to add a MouseListener to an image?

Tags: java, image, swing, custom-component, mouselistener

I'm working on a card game in Java.  I already have a Card class that knows how to paint itself.  I'd like to have the Card output its rank and suit to the console when the user clicks on it.  Unfortunately I'm having problems implementing this feature.

Here's a slimmed down version of what I have so far:

```
public class Card  extends Component {

  private Rank rank;
  private Suit suit;
  // Note: Rank and Suit are enums

  public String toString() {
    String rank = this.rank.name().toLowerCase();
    String suit = this.suit.name().toLowerCase();

    return (rank + " of " + suit);
  }

  // ...
}

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(410, 320);
    frame.setContentPane(new MyPanel());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private Card card;

  public MyPanel() {
    card = new Card();

    card.setRank(Rank.ACE);
    card.setSuit(Suit.SPADE);
    card.addMouseListener(this);

    addMouseListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {    
    Object source = mouseEvent.getSource();

    if(source instanceof Card) {
      Card card = (Card) source;
      System.out.println(card);
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("not a card : " + source);
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

I don't want to extend from JLabel since addMouseListener is all I really need and that's inherited from the Component class.

Alternatively, instead of extending from Component, I could have the Card class itself check if the location of the MouseEvent is within the boundaries of the Card image.  I don't like this idea because it means I'd have to do boundary checks for all 52 cards.

Comment: *"I don't like this idea because it means I'd have to do boundary checks for all 52 cards."*  No, you won't, the machine running the code will.  And trust me, it will be able to handle it.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  Why create an event processing loop when Java should be able to handle it internally?  After all, if Java can detect that the user clicked the mouse on a JButton, why can't it do it for custom components?

Comment: Well I just solved it.  The problem was that I needed to set the bounds of the card (with setBounds).  So Java knew how to draw the card, but didn't know where it was located on the JPanel.

Comment: I went back to manually checking if the user clicked on the card. Double buffering with setBounds was just impossible.